# Same name methods in different modules cause ambiguity

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 modules. Each contains a Sub with the same name. See below:

```
Module moduleA
    Public Sub f(ByVal arg1 As myType)
        Console.WriteLine("module A")
    End Sub
End Module

Module moduleB
    Public Sub f(ByVal arg1 As myType, ByVal arg2 As Boolean)
        Console.WriteLine("module B")
    End Sub
End Module
```

But the compiler complains that there's ambiguity between moduleA and moduleB.

How could this be? I have totally different signatures.

However, if I put the 2 methods into the same module, there's no ambiguity at all.

Could someone tell me why?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why dont you place both functions into the same module? I think because both modules are for different purposes. So wheres the problem to make a call like moduleB.f(...) ?
Besides its easier to understand for everybody (including yourself) who will see your code later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to fully qualify method calls in order to stop the ambiguity. e.g.  `moduleA.f()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why can't the compiler distinguish them just by the signature? Some kind of overloading?

Comment: @smwikipedia: what is the compiler warning that you are getting?

Comment: @Ardman, 'f' is ambiguous between declarations in Modules 'TestProject.moduleA' and 'TestProject.moduleB'.

Comment: @smwikipedia: which is why you'll have to use the fully qualified name for each of these.